# Where is Fat Joe from?

Tags: history, rap

Where does Fat Joe, the famous American rapper, come from? His musical genre is Rap, and he sang "Make it rain".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Joseph Antonio Cartagena (born August 19, 1970), better known by his stage name Fat Joe, is an American rapper from **New York City**.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [Fat Joe - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_Joe)

> "Make It Rain" is a song by American rapper Fat Joe, released in 2006 as the first single from his seventh album Me, Myself & I.

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_It_Rain_(Fat_Joe_song)